# Android : how to programatically determine whether the system has a 3G/4G radio?

Tags: android, networking, modem, 4g

I am programming a Nexus 7 and need to determine whether the system has a 3G/4G radio or not.  How do I do that?

Comment: A modem?  Why would it have a modem?  Do you mean a wifi radio, or a 3G/4G radio?

Comment: Yes I do mean 3G/4G radios.  Such radios are also called radio modems where I work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `TelephonyManager.getPhoneType ()`.  Returned values are

```
PHONE_TYPE_NONE
PHONE_TYPE_GSM
PHONE_TYPE_CDMA
PHONE_TYPE_SIP
```

Checking if CDMA or GSM should work

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just check for the presence of a mobile network type.

```
boolean hasRadio()
{
     ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

     return (connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) != null);
}
```